# Is it safe to pass const reference to temporary/annonymous lambda into std::thread constructor?

Tags: c++, lambda, pass-by-reference, stdthread

Following on from this question: [can-a-temperary-lambda-by-passed-by-reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49981481/c-can-a-temperary-lambda-by-passed-by-reference-works-on-msvc-windows-but-not)

I have a fixed code snippet:

```
// global variable
std::thread worker_thread;

// Template function
template <typename Functor>
void start_work(const Functor &worker_fn)  // lambda passed by const ref
{
    worker_thread = std::thread([&](){
        worker_fn();
    });
}
```

This is called like this:

```
void do_work(int value)
{
    printf("Hello from worker\r\n");
}

int main()
{
    // This lambda is a temporary variable...
    start_work([](int value){ do_work(value) });
}
```

This seems to work, but I am concerned about passing a temporary lambda into the thread constructor since the thread will run, but the function start_work() will return and the temp-lambda will go out of scope.

However I was looking at the std::thread constructor which is defined:

> thread() noexcept; (1)  (since C++11)
>
> thread( thread&& other ) noexcept; (2)  (since C++11)
>
> template< class Function, class... Args > 
>   explicit thread( Function&& f, Args&&... args ); (3)  (since C++11)
>
> thread(const thread&) = delete; (4)  (since C++11)

So I am assuming that the constructor 3 is called:

```
template< class Function, class... Args >
explicit thread( Function&& f, Args&&... args );
```

I struggle to understand what is written here, but it looks like it would try to move the lambda `&&` which I believe is ok for temp variables.

So is what I have done in my code snippet dangerous (i.e. the ref goes out of scope) or correct (i.e. the temp is moved and all is well)? or neither??

An alternative is to just pass my value (make a copy) which is not so bad anyway in this case.

Comment: Upped as promised. A full answer is above my pay grade.

Comment: You have a dangling reference.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux sorry... yes I did mean that, typo, fixed!

Comment: @PasserBy can you expand on that, I thought that the temp would be "moved" by the `std::thread(Function && f ...)` constructor, which I thought was ok?

Comment: The question is asking if it's ok to pass a `const &` to a temporary to `std::thread`, and it is. But it's not what you are doing. Rather, the problem here is that you are capturing a temporary by reference in a lambda, which isn't the same thing and isn't ok in this context.

Comment: Briefly, the lambda may well be moved correctly, but the thing it's capturing will not be. As a charlatan, I think of lambdas as being no more than fancy function objects.

Comment: Your code does not compile on clang, `error: 'do_work' in capture list does not name a variable`. This capture is not needed. The lambda does not capture anything and I'd say it's just a function pointer whitch explain why there are no dangling pointers. You can effectively write `start_work(do_work)`

Comment: @Bathsheba ah, so I could fix that by using `[=]` or more specifically `[worker_fn](){...}`?

Comment: @GuillaumeGris yes, it is a function pointer - I had to convert from a class function to this example - so I missed that, I'll remove the "do_work" capture, thanks

Comment: @GuillaumeGris also yes, I could write start_work(do_work), but this is just a code snippet, the real function does more, I was just trying to make a minimal example : )

Comment: This might help you understand the problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7941562/what-is-the-lifetime-of-a-c-lambda-expression

Comment: @code_fodder Consider making `worker_fn` a forwarding reference (`Functor&& worker_fn`) and initializing your capture with `std::forward`.

Comment: What I'm trying to say is as long as your lambda does not capture anything, then there are no problems

Comment: You don't need any of the lambda's in this example. `start_work(do_work);` and `worker_thread = std::thread(worker_fn);` do the same thing (both are missing the `value` parameter for the `do_work` call)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*A* temporary is indeed moved but it is the "inner" one, the argument to `std::thread`.

That temporary holds a reference to the "outer" temporary, the argument to `start_work`, and whose lifetime ends after `start_work` has returned.

Thus, your "inner" lambda object holds a reference to an object that may or may not exist during its execution, which is very unsafe.

Comment: ah ok... so in "theory" I could change the inner capture to `[=]` to capture by copy and that should be safe (there will be one copy, but that's better then two)?

Comment: @code_fodder As long as you make sure that the thing you're capturing also hasn't captured any references that can be left dangling, yes.

Answer (score 3):

A lambda is an anonymous `struct` in C++. If we were to translate the snippet to an equivalent one without lambdas, it would become

```
template <typename Functor>
void start_work(const Functor &worker_fn)
{
    struct lambda {
        const Functor& worker_fn;
        auto operator()() const { worker_fn(); }
    };
    worker_thread = std::thread(lambda{worker_fn});
}
```

`lambda` has a non-stack-based const reference as a member, which would dangle as soon as `start_work` returns, regardless whether the `lambda` object itself is copied.

Comment: Is that because I am capturing by reference (e.g. `[&]`) and I could instead capture by copy `[=]`?

Comment: @code_fodder Yes. It would be `Functor worker_fn;` if capture by copy.